# Search through dictionary key with string, not object

Tags: python, string, dictionary, key

I'm trying to extract values froma key in a dictinoary, but when I search for the key, I want to use a 'string' and not an object. Right now, with dict.get, it tells me I need to search for a key with an object, so is there another built in function or anything that can search for a key with a string and not an object?

```
dict.get('someKey',' ')# looks for the key 'someKey'. If that key isn't found, a blank ' ' is returned
```

AFTER ANSWERS:

Thanks everyone! So it would look something like:

```
yourDictionary.get('someKey',' ')# looks for the key 'someKey' in dictionary 'yourDictinoary'. If that key isn't found, a blank ' ' is returned
```

Comment: Um, a string _is_ an object.  What do you mean by "not an object"?

Comment: I thought an object is a predeclared variable. Am I mistaken?

Comment: If you have {'someKey': 10}.get('someKey', '') this will return 10. What's your doubt?

Comment: I guess I just misunderstood .get, but thanks for the info everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion is due to the way you are calling `dict.get()` - it is an instance method, so the first argument, if called on the class `dict`, should be a dictionary instance. Otherwise, you will get a `TypeError`:

```
>>> dict.get("key", "default")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    dict.get("key", "default")
TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'
```

If you have used OOP yet in Python, note that this is related to the implicit first argument `self` in methods you write for classes.

You can fix this by passing an instance explicitly:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> dict.get(d, "key", "default")
'default'
```

Alternatively (and preferably), call the method on the instance itself:

```
>>> d.get("key", "default")
'default'
```

---

As for your comment, you *can* alternatively use any of:

```
try:
    result = d["key"]
except KeyError:
    result = "default"
```

or

```
if "key" in d:
    result = d["key"]
else:
    result = "default"
```

or

```
result = d["key"] if key in d else "default"
```

to achieve the same as `result = d.get("key", "default")`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to search for a key in the dict type itself. That's why the interpreter says you need to search for a key with an object.

You should first create a dict object and then search for keys in it (of course after adding some data if you want to find something).

```
d = dict()  # or d = {}
d['someKey'] = 1
print d.get('someKey', ' ')  # will print 1
print d.get('otherKey', ' ')  # will print a space
```